# How much does including an unused function cost?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, include, cpu-usage

I have a lot of useful vbscript functions and I include all of them at once in every asp package I create. Perhaps I wont use some of them. e.g.

```
<!--#include file="teststring.asp"-->
```

How much does **including** a function cost? (I mean cpu usage) and how much important is to excerpt only the used functions?

Answer (score 1):

unless your web site has a huge number of visitors and is process intensive, I don't see the performance being affected. Even if that IS the case, it would still be so minuscule that, to the average user, it wouldn't be noticeable.